# is there a way to lock my pc completely for a specific time?

Tags: windows-10, hp-pavilion, hp-laptop

I use a HP Pavilion ab253cl laptop running windows 10 home. I am kind of addicted to the laptop and couldn't make productive use of my time. most of the time, i kill my time doiong random stuff on laptop. Is there a way by which i can lock this laptop for a certain time, so that even i couldn't unlock it until the time lapses?? I tried searching for a solution, but couldn't find any. Please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: This is mainly a wetware problem. Any restrictions you put in place you can also remove so are ultimately going to be useless. Deal with your issues first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this with software (if you can do it you can undo it), but you could do something like get a solid box which takes a padlock, buy some padlocks (mark which key opens which one), open all the padlocks, freeze each of the keys in an ice cube [ or bigger, depending on the time lapse ], put laptop in box, lock with  padlock, remove key from freezer and you more-or-less need to wait for it to melt.

There are plenty of twists on this theme, depending on how secure you want to make it, how long etc.